# how to pass the outputs from Get metadata stage and use it for file name comparison in databricks notebook

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have 2 Get metadata stages in ADF which is fetching file names from 2 different folders, I need to use these outputs for file name comparison in databricks notebook and return true if all the files are present.

how to pass the output from Get meta data stages to databricks and perform string comparison and
return true if all files are present and return false if even 1 file is missing

How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please include the image of your pipeline and with what are you comparing the list of file names from `Get metadata` in databricks notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below answer which I explained with 1 Get metadata stage , the same can be replicated for more than one also.

Create an ADF pipeline with below activities.
[image: Sample ADF Pipeline to replicate scenario]

Now in the Get Metadata activity , add the childItems in the Fieldlist as argument, to pass the output of Get Metadata to Notebook as show below
[image: Argument list in Get Metadata]

In the Databricks Notebook activity , add the below parameter as Base Paramter which will capture the output of Get Metadata and pass as input paramater to Notebook. Generally this parameter will of object datatype , but I converted to string datatype to access the names of files in the notebook as show below
[image: Base Parameter in Notebook activity]

```
@string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems)
```

Now we can able to access the Get Metadata output as string in the notebook.

```
import ast
required_filenames = ['File1.csv','File2.csv','File3.csv'] ##This is for comparing with the output we get from GetMetadata activity.
metadata_value = dbutils.widgets.get('metadata_output') ##Accessing the output from Get Metadata and storing into a variable using databricks widgets.
metadata_list = ast.literal_eval(metadata_value) ##Converting the above string datatype to the list datatype.
```

---

```
blob_output_list=[] ##Creating an empty list to add the names of files we get from GetMetadata activity.
for i in metadata_list:
   blob_output_list.append(i['name']) ##This will add all the names of files from blob storage to the empty list we created above.
```

---

```
validateif = all(item in blob_output_list for item in required_filenames) ##This  validateif variable now compare both the lists using list comprehension and provide either True or False.
```

---

I tried in the above way and can able to solve the provided requirement. Hope this helps.
**Request to please upvote the answer if this helps in your requirement.**

Comment: @harshith did this answer your question? solved your problem.

Comment: Good looking, clear answer. A bit of supporting documentation would make it great :+1: